# Image not showing in .pdf after creating in from .md using pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I've been trying to create .pdf file from .md using pandoc. I've used code: pandoc file.md -o file.pdf, but got 2 warnings:

[WARNING] Could not fetch resource ./Documentation/logo.jpg: replacing image with description

[WARNING] Could not fetch resource ./Documentation/diagram.png: replacing image with description

It has created new pdf called file.pdf, but images are not included there, some ideas how to solve it? The images are under ## Logo of our application and under ## Diagram for application.

````
# Travelhelper 

## Table of Contents

* [Project documentation](Documentation/000_project_documentation)
  * [JavaDoc documentation](Documentation/000_project_documentation)
* [UML diagrams](Documentation/001_uml_diagrams)
* [Versions](Documentation/002_versions)
* [Technical details](Documentation/003_tech_details)
* [Simulation and demonstration](Documentation/004_simulation_and_demonstration)  
  * [Video demonstration](Documentation/004_simulation_and_demonstration)

## Application description

Travelhelper, your ultimate application for room-booking. Rather than spending a lot of time on unclear booking us come to room-booking app and find the best accommodation for you.

## How does it work

In the beginning you can see loginning in scene, where user can choose if he wants to directly log in or register before loginning in, if he is not yet. Then the main menu shows to the user after successfull loginning in the app. The user can see 4 buttons there: Info, Booking, Profile, Log out. After pressing Info button another scene with informations about the application shows up to the user with our app logo. After pressing booking button easy user interface is shown where user can choose room type and depending on the chosen type of the room (Standard room, Luxury room or Suite room) price of the accommodation is shown. 

## What I will add 

I'm planning to add Profile scene where informations about the user are shown and he can change his password and so on...

## Logo of our application

![Logo](./Documentation/logo.jpg){ width=200px height=200px }

## Diagram for application

![Diagram](./Documentation/diagram.png){ width=400px height=400px }

## Main 

This code runs the application
```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
```

Also, there is one method which loads.fxml, scene responsible for loginning in the application and other functionalities such as setting the title to the Login form, width and height of the scene and loading the scene. 

## MainController

There are three methods such as switchToInfoScene, switchToRoomsScene, switchToProfileScene and method responsible for handling log out button. 

```java
    public void logout(ActionEvent event) {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Logout");
        alert.setHeaderText("You're about to logout");
        alert.setContentText("Do you really want to quit? ");

        if (alert.showAndWait().get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            stage = (Stage) scenePane.getScene().getWindow();
            System.out.println("You successfully logged out");
            stage.close();
        }
    }
```

We set the title to "Logout", header to the: "You're about to logout" and content text to: "Do you really want to quit?"

If the log out button is pressed user can click "Cancel" button he returns back to the main menu, but if he clicks "OK" the application will close. 

```java
  if (alert.showAndWait().get() == ButtonType.OK) {...}
```

This is the check for OK button, so it closes after clicking it.

## LoginController

In this class is another method called handleLoginButtonAction, which gets username and password of the user. If user is not null and users password is right then main scene is loaded. Icon of the application is our logo, which is shown in the beginning of the documentation and title is the name of our app. If the mentioned conditions are not followed then error is thrown with the title set to: "Login Failed" and context is set to: "Incorrect username or password. Please try again." and waits until users decision.


## RegisterController

In this class is method called handeRegisterButtonAction, where user can set the name, username and password. 

```java
  if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty()) {...}
```

if either one of the fields is not fieled then it's going to throw an error.

```java
  if (LoginController.registeredUsers.containsKey(username)) {...}
```

This line of code checks that if the other user does not already use this username. 

If everything is OK, then new user is created and it sets the titel to: "Registration is successful" and writes out: "You have successfully registered. You can now log in." And also it opens login form.

## InfoController and ProfileController

Both of those classes include switchToMainScene, which are responsible for switching to main menu after clicking "back to menu" button. In the InfoController there are informations about my game.

## Room class and iherited subclasses (polymorphism is included there as well)

In the room class I created constructor and two methods: getPrice() and getType() method, which are overriden in those three inherited classes: standard room, luxury room and suite room. 

## RoomsController

In this class we are handling mentioned classes depending on the chosen room type. 

```java
  priceLabel.setText(String.format("%.2f", room.getPrice()) + " €");
```

This line of code is responsible for calculating the price for selected room type and printining it out in this scene.

## Using abstract class, inheritance and polymorphism
````

Comment: Can you try with the full path to the image?

Comment: Well it's working all right right now, well but I'm posting it on my repository in github, won't it cause any problems in showing .md file? Doing this for my first time, so rather asking. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a pandoc user, but maybe try https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3752#issuecomment-1004352568